# How to compute the total number of directions in this graph?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

If we draw a certain number, say $m$ layered hexagons as in the picture on a triangular grid graph, are we able to determine the number of directions in the graph in any way? By the directions I mean different directions created by picking two different points in the graph (so any two points from any of the layers, they can be in the same layer or a different layer). For example, if $m=1$ we would only have $6$ different directions (this comes from the directions found from the points of a regular hexagon), for $m=2$ we would have the total of $18$ different directions (if we count the different directions determined by all the points in two layered hexagons) and so on. I do not know if there's a pattern here or something like that, but I would like to know how could one either count the directions in general just for some $m$ or similar? Thanks.

*Layered hexagons*[image]

Comment: can you provide a more rigorous definition of *direction* or provide a more detailed calculation of how you arrived at 6 and 18 respectively for $m=1,2$. This would help others to understand the question.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by a "direction" but take two adjacent vertical lines in your diagram. Pick one point (any point) from each - they define a "direction". Fix the first point. You get as many directions as you like. Or is there more to it than that?

Comment: I edited the post. Directions are essentially defined as in slopes between all the points in a configuration. For instance, if you have a regular hexagon, this determines the total of $6$ directions (which you get by connecting all the points in the hexagon - these form different slopes, particularly $0$, $\infty$, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},\sqrt{3},-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},-\sqrt{3}$).

Comment: is the origin permitted as a point to construct a slope?

Comment: Yes it is, you can of course count it as a point. The configuration in total would consist of the center point, 6 points on the first layer, then 12 points on the second layer, then 18 points on the third layer and so on. So the total number of points in the configuration would have to be odd.